# Upgrade to Spring boot 3 with Jakarta EE throws a runtime exception Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to upgrade my project from Spring boot 2.7.2 to 3.
the project depends on a library that contains the entity classes. Following is the pom.xml for the library, where I have moved from package javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence for all the entities:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <datarepository.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</datarepository.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackson.version>2.14.0</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The import of postgresql in DataModel may be would conflict with the imported one in spring boot API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--The strope artificat should be moved to the new artifcate to be created fr credit Card processor-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripe-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <!--Has been added for emailExecutorSenderTest. Once the class has been moved to a module, remove this dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and my project's pom.xml dependency for spring boot 3 is as folow:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <core.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.businessintelligence</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
            <version>0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Try to remove this dependency from API because it does not use Redis anyway and
        that is because the core has dependency to redis template for sale and stockManager which
        share the same objects RedisHash.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAXB RI, Jakarta XML Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit Jupiter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

here is the config of my database connection for more details:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource datasource) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setShowSql(false);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        fb.setPackagesToScan("net.businessintelligence"); // It is likely we do not need this line to be tested
        fb.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        fb.setDataSource(datasource);
        fb.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory) {
        return factory.getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }
```

When I try to start the project, it throws the following exception with stack trace:

```
2023-02-25T09:34:52.905-05:00 ERROR 24662 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
        - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(net.company.entity.entityName) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation


    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...

    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.execute(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CteInsertStrategy can only be used with Dialects that support CTE that can take UPDATE or DELETE statements as well
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.getFallbackSqmInsertStrategy(PostgreSQLDialect.java:828) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMutationStrategyHelper.resolveInsertStrategy(SqmMutationStrategyHelper.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.interpretSqmMultiTableInsertStrategy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5972) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$prepareMappingModel$12(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5825) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        ... 30 common frames omitte
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it after debugging further I fixed it by updating the
hibernate.dialect from org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect as a reference to this doc
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.java